# Can you compute the average fidelity of two qubits by averaging over a finite number of states?

Tags: fidelity, gate-fidelity

For a single qubit and a quantum operation, the fidelity
$$
F_{|\psi\rangle\!\langle \psi|} = \mathrm{Tr}\bigg(U | \psi \rangle\!\langle \psi | U^\dagger \mathcal M\big(| \psi \rangle\!\langle \psi |\big)\bigg),
$$

averaged over all possible initial states $|\psi\rangle$ (i.e., over the Bloch sphere) can be calculated by the fidelity averaged over the six states $|\pm\rangle,|\pm\rangle_x,|\pm \rangle_y$ (see this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0201106)).

Is there a similar result for two qubits or more?

Comment: Could you add more details to your question? Please make your question independent of references.

Comment: have you come across the concept of a quantum $t$-design? I'm not overly familiar with the details, but the broad concept is that a $t$-design gives a set of states on up to $t$ qubits that, for calculating averages, is as good as averaging over all possible states. IIRC the Clifford group (i.e. stabilizer states) serves your purpose.

Comment: @DaftWullie No, do you have a good reference for it that is not too mathematical?

Comment: These things have a habit of getting very technical very quickly!

Answer (score 1):

You can, as long as the states form a complex-projective 2-design.

To see it, start from expanding the given expression and observing that it is linear in $\mathbb{P}_\psi\otimes\mathbb{P}_\psi$, where $\mathbb{P}_\psi\equiv|\psi\rangle\!\langle \psi|$.
More explicitly, this means that it can be reframed as an expression of the form
$$F_{\psi}= \langle A, \mathbb{P}_\psi\otimes\mathbb{P}_\psi\rangle
\equiv \operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger(\mathbb{P}_\psi\otimes\mathbb{P}_\psi)),$$
for some operator $A$ that you can find explicitly expanding all terms in your definition.

Therefore when averaging the fidelity over all states, you are effectively averaging over $\mathbb{P}_\psi\otimes\mathbb{P}_\psi$ over all (uniformly random) states $\psi$. A complex-projective 2-design is defined as a finite set of vectors such that averaging this quantity over these vectors equals the average over all states, hence the result. See *e.g.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_t-design for more info.